# Problems using phonegap / cordova file plugin part 1

Tags: file, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I want to add some simple logging capabilities to my cordova app.

So I added the file plugin, implemented a super simple log method and tested.

My configuration:

```
    $ cordova --version
    3.5.0-0.2.7

    $ cordova plugins
    org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.0 "File"
```

The test device is a Huawei u8850, running Android 2.3.5

The Logger:

```
window.MyLog = {
    log: function(line){
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(FS) {
            FS.root.getFile('the_log1.txt', {"create":true, "exclusive":false},
                function(fileEntry) {
                    fileEntry.createWriter(
                        function(writer) {
                            console.log(line);
                            writer.seek(writer.length);     // append to eof
                            writer.write(line + '\n');      // write the line
                        }, fail);
                }, fail);
        }, fail);
    }
};
```

Testing:

```
    MyLog.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
```

All seems fine:

- file was created, line was inserted
- when starting the app again, the line was appended

But then:
I tried to write some extra chars:

```
window.MyLog = {
    log: function(line){
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(FS) {
            FS.root.getFile('the_log2.txt', {"create":true, "exclusive":false},
                function(fileEntry) {
                    fileEntry.createWriter(
                        function(writer) {
                            console.log(line);
                            writer.seek(writer.length);     // append to eof
                            writer.write(line + '\n');      // write the line
                            writer.write('----' + '\n');    // extra write
                        }, fail);
                }, fail);
        }, fail);
    }
};
```

I found this log cat output:

```
    16:00:00
    processMessage failed: Error: [object Object]
    processMessage failed: Stack: undefined
    processMessage failed: Message: S01 File218896726 {"lastModifiedDate":1409839200000,"fullPath":"\/the_log2.txt","type":"text\/plain","name":"the_log2.txt","size":0}
```

-> seemingly it is not possible to use the writer.write command more than once

Q:

- Why is this happening? Is it a bug or a feature?
- is there any documentation / sample code available on the usage of this plugin?
    (the docs found here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md are not as comprehensive as I would like)

Comment: did you try implementing the `onwriteend()` event callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to implement and wait for the `onwriteend()` event to fire after writing anything to a file.

Once the `onwriteend()` fired you can write again to the file.

What I was doing when I created a logging feature was something like this (you can use it as a guide, i'm just typing it out of my head):

```
function fileItemSuccessWrite(writer){
    writer.seek(writer.length);

    writer.onwriteend = function(e) {
         // TODO WRITE AGAIN
    };

    writer.onerror = function(e) {
         // HANDLE ERROR
    };

    writer.write(YOUR_LOG_TO_WRITE);

}
fileEntry.createWriter(fileItemSuccessWrite, fileItemFailWrite);
```

Also what I have created was a `cache` (a `tmp_variable`) for the content I wanted to write in a log file. Once this `tmp_variable` reached a specific size I dumped it in the log file. So it was lighter on `fileSystem` access.

You can read about the `writer` and `write` on [**W3.org**](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-writer.html#the-filewriter-interface)

Comment: I see. I really had to read the docs. Using the onwriteend method is the key.  But since the file is a log, I had to ensure that lines are appended quickly - a cache is not an option in that context. I'm currently writing a small text file wrapper with some basic functionality, so an app can easily append lines without dealing with the asyn implementation of the file interface. I will upload that code as an answer to my second question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668876/problems-using-phonegap-cordova-file-plugin-part-2-synchronicity