# Problems using phonegap / cordova file plugin part 2 - synchronicity

Tags: file, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I want to add some simple logging capabilities to my cordova app.

So I added the file plugin, implemented a super simple log method and tested.

My configuration:

```
    $ cordova --version
    3.5.0-0.2.7

    $ cordova plugins
    org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.0 "File"
```

The test device is a Huawei u8850, running Android 2.3.5

The Logger:

```
window.MyLog = {
    log: function(line){
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(FS) {
            FS.root.getFile('the_log3.txt', {"create":true, "exclusive":false},
                function(fileEntry) {
                    fileEntry.createWriter(
                        function(writer) {
                            console.log(line);
                            writer.seek(writer.length);     // append to eof
                            writer.write(line + '\n');      // write the line
                        }, fail);
                }, fail);
        }, fail);
    }
};
```

Testing:

```
    MyLog.log('A ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
    MyLog.log('B ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
    MyLog.log('C ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
```

I started the app 3 times, expected sth. like

```
A 16:03:47
B 16:03:47
C 16:03:47
A 16:04:34
B 16:04:34
C 16:04:34
A 16:04:41
B 16:04:41
C 16:04:41
```

but got this

```
C 16:03:47
C 16:04:34
A 16:04:41
```

There are 2 Problems:

1. not all lines are in the log
2. it is undefined which line happens to be written

I think the reason for the problems is the asynchronous nature of the file methods. But this is just a guess.

The question are:

1. How can I implement a method to append lines to a text file, assuring that no line is missing and the order of the lines is the same as the calls to the method?
2. Do I have to use synchronous versions of file methods?
3. If yes: Is there any documentation / sample code available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include "stdio.h"

void appendLine(char* path_to_file, char* line) {
    FILE* fp = fopen(path_to_file, "a");
    if (fp) {
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", line);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}

int main(){
    appendLine("logfile.txt", "One Line");
    appendLine("logfile.txt", "Another Line");
    return 0;
}
```

this is written in an ancient language called "C".

Just 4 lines of code:

1. fopen   : opens an existing file or creates a new one, file position at end ("a" for append)
2. if (fp) : check if file object is created
3. fprintf : do it!
4. fclose  : close it (and flush contents)

It can be compiled with this command:

```
gcc -Wall addline.c -o addline
```

and started like so:

```
./addline
```

the output will be like that:

```
One Line
Another Line
```

Unfortunately this cannot be done when writing a JS based application with phonegap / cordova.

For unknown reasons a simple synchronous interface for basic file operations is not part of phonegaps core implementation, additionally is not included in the 'file' plugin.

So I spent some time to implement a simple TextFile wrapper to do the dirty work, so a client app can use simple commands like these:

```
// a single object is the wrapper:
var textFile;

function init() {
    // ...

    // initialize the (log) file
    // the file will be created if doesn't exists
    // when sth. goes wrong, the callback has an error message
    textFile = new TextFile('logfile.txt', function(ok, msg){
        if (!ok) {
            alert('logging not available' + (msg ? '\nError: ' + msg : ''));
            textFile = null;
        } else {
            textFile.writeLine('start logging ...');
            start();
        }
    },
    {
        // optional options, currently just one property 'clear' is supported
        // if set to true, the file will be emptied at start
        clear: true
    }
);


// later, use methods

// append some lines
textFile.writeLine('a line');
textFile.writeLine('another line');

// get content, callback needed since it is not synchronous
textFile.getContent(function(text){
    // show text
});

// empty file
textFile.clear();

// remove file
textFile.remove();
```

I use jquery for merging options - if jquery is not appropriate, just replace the $.extend method.

here's the code:

```
/**
 * Created by martin on 9/3/14.
 *
 * requires the file plugin:
 *
 * cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
 *
 * implemented and tested with
 *   cordova-3.5.0-0.2.7
 * on
 *   Android 2.3.5
 */



(function(){
    'use strict';

    // these values are NOT part of FileWriter, so we had to define them:
    const INIT = 0;
    const WRITING = 1;
    const DONE = 2;

    function errMessage(code){
        var msg = '';

        switch (code) {
            case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
                msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
                break;
            case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
                break;
            case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
                msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
                break;
            case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
                msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
                break;
            case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
                msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
                break;
            default:
                msg = 'Unknown Error';
                break;
        };

        return msg;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param fileName  : the name of the file for which the TextFile is created
     * @param cb        : function, is called when
     *                    - TextFile is created, parameter: boolean true
     *                    - TextFile is not created, parameters: boolean false, string error_message
     * @param options   : object with single property
     *                    - boolean clear - truncates the file, defaults to false
     * @constructor
     */
    window.TextFile = function(fileName, cb, options){
        this.writer = null;
        this.queue = [];

        this.fileEntry = null;

        this._initialize(fileName, cb, options);
    }

    var files = {};

    TextFile.prototype = {
        // pseudo private method, called form constructor
        _initialize: function(fileName, cb, options){

            this.options = $.extend({startMsg: null, clear: false}, options)

            if (files.fileName) {
                cb(false, 'TextFile[' + fileName + '] already in use');
            }
            files.fileName = true;
            var that = this;
            window.requestFileSystem(
                LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,
                0,
                function(FS) {
                    FS.root.getFile(
                        fileName,
                        {
                            'create': true,
                            'exclusive': false
                        },
                        function(fileEntry) {
                            that.fileEntry = fileEntry;
                            fileEntry.createWriter(
                                function(writer) {
                                    that.writer = writer;
                                    writer.seek(writer.length);
                                    writer.onwriteend = function(){
                                        if (that.queue.length > 0){
                                            // sth in the queue
                                            var item = that.queue[0];
                                            switch (item.type) {
                                                case 'w':
                                                    writer.write(item.line + '\n');
                                                    break;
                                                case 't':
                                                    writer.truncate(0);
                                                    break;
                                                case 'g':
                                                    that._readContent(item.cb);
                                                    break;

                                                default:
                                                    throw 'unknown type ' + item.type;
                                            }

                                            // get rid of processed item
                                            that.queue.splice(0, 1);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (that.options.clear) {
                                        that.clear();
                                    }
                                    cb(true);
                                }
                            );
                        },
                        function(err){
                            cb(false, errMessage(err.code))
                        }
                    );
                },
                function(){
                    cb(false, errMessage(err.code));
                }
            );
        },

        // internal use
        _readContent: function(cb){
            this.fileEntry.file(function(file) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                        var res = this.result;
                        cb(res);
                    };

                    reader.readAsText(file);
                },
                function(err) {
                    cb('got an error: ' + errMessage(err.code));
                }
            );
        },

        // reads whole file, content is sent to client with callback
        getContent: function(cb){
            if (this.writer.readyState !== WRITING) {
                this._readContent(cb);
            } else {
                this.queue.push({type: 'g', cb:cb});
            }
        },

        // set file size to zero
        clear: function() {
            if (this.writer.readyState !== WRITING) {
                this.writer.truncate(0);
            } else {
                this.queue.push({type: 't'});
            }
        },

        // removes file
        remove: function(cb){
            this.fileEntry.remove(
                function(){
                    if (cb) {
                        cb(true);
                    }
                },
                function(err){
                    if (cb) {
                        cb(false,errMessage(err.code));
                    }
                }
            );
        },

        // append single line to file
        writeLine: function(line){
            if (this.writer.readyState !== WRITING) {
                this.writer.write(line + '\n');
            } else {
                this.queue.push({type: 'w', line: line});
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

Maybe this is useful for others, struggling with the same problem ...

Answer (score 1):

Probably you were trying to write before previous writes finished, and fired the `onwriteend` event.

As posted in my answer on your first question, it is a good idea to implement a `caching` function.

So all your logs will be stored in a temporery `cache`. Every time you add something to this `cache` you will check the size of it, once it reaches a limit defined by you, call a `logDumping` method, which will be the actual `write` to the log file.

When you call the `dump` method you can pass the log content to your writer and also empty your cache so you can store new content in it and it won't get overlapped with already *logged* content.

What I would do is:

1. `cache` the log
2. check if `cache` reached a size limit
3. pass content of `cache` to a `tmp_var` and clear `cache`
4. write `tmp_var` to logfile
5. check `onwriteend` > if successful clear `tmp_var`, if there was an error you can write your `tmp_var` back to your actual `cache` (hence not loosing any data), and try writing the content of your `cache` to your logfile again.